# C & CXX Compiler Issues - Multiple definitions

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, makefile, cmake

Im working on a game that uses SFML. Currently the project uses a CMakeCCCompilerId.c and CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp in a directory 'CMakeFiles'

I'm getting the following errors below:

```
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/305235777/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `info_compiler'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/1773982079/CMakeCCompilerId.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/305235777/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o:(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `info_platform'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/1773982079/CMakeCCompilerId.o:(.data+0x8): first defined here
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/305235777/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o:(.data+0x10): multiple definition of `info_arch'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/1773982079/CMakeCCompilerId.o:(.data+0x10):  first defined here
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/305235777/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o: In function `main':
/home/rob/NetBeansProjects/development/projects/sfml- tmxloader/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp:368: multiple  definition of `main'
 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/1773982079/CMakeCCompilerId.o:/home/rob/NetBeansProjects/development/projects/sfml-tmxloader/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c:378: first defined here

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/581045564/Benchmark.o: In function `main':
/home/rob/NetBeansProjects/development/projects/sfml-   tmxloader/examples/Benchmark.cpp:89: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/1773982079/CMakeCCompilerId.o:/home/rob/NetBeansProjects/development/projects/sfml-tmxloader/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c:378: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/levelrender] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory  `/home/rob/NetBeansProjects/development/projects/LevelRender'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rob/NetBeansProjects/development/projects/LevelRender'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing C and C++ in CMake, what CMakeCCompilerId.c and how can I discard it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737066/mixing-c-and-c-in-cmake-what-cmakeccompilerid-c-and-how-can-i-discard-it)

Comment: I suspect you only want to use one of the two files, but more likely you are building/configuring in your source directory and using globs as in the other question I linked. @Mike Seymour, these files are created by CMake, so the OP can't edit them, or put them in a header. I have numerous CMake systems which use `project(... C CXX)` and mix the languages. The key is in buiding out of tree

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, fixed by adding `CXX` to:

```
project(project_name CXX)
```